# Can your companion Soul Trap?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If you give your traveling companion a weapon with a Soul Trap enchantment and some assorted Soul Gems, can they Soul Trap creatures that they kill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they can!

This is an easy way to take some of the hassle and headache out of the whole soul-management process.

Just be sure to keep the weapon you've given them recharged.

Comment: And make sure you provide them with unfilled soul gems :) It also makes a difference what companion you use. My Lydia (RIP... *sniffle*) used a Soul Trap bow or sword consistently, but when I have a mage companion, they never really seem to use any weapons I provide, even if they equip a dagger when we walk around town, so I wouldn't use a mage companion for help filling soul gems.